# EPERM error when running Gulp as non-root

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm using Gulp to compile some assets on a simple standalone WordPress theme project.

When I run my gulp task that compiles some LESS files I get the following error:

```
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: EPERM, chmod '/Users/harryg/Sites/sites/wordpress/wp-content/themes/samarkand-2/assets/css/main.min.css'
```

When I run it as `sudo` the task executes without problem.

Thinking it was a permissions error I chmod'd the entire theme folder and its contents to 777 but this doesn't solve the problem. I have gulp installed globally which may be the issue but I'm not sure how to solve.

**EDIT**

Even if I run the local gulp I get the same error. I.e. running `node_modules/.bin/gulp` from my project folder produces the same EPERM error.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but you should avoid running gulp as root. That's kind of dangerous. Instead, chmod the project directory to 777 (i.e. `'/Users/harryg/Sites/sites/wordpress/wp-content/themes/samarkand-2'`)

Comment: @Tom chmod to 777 is dangerous as well

Comment: In my case, some packages in package.json had older versions and I had to install the latest ones.

Answer (score 2):

```
`sudo chown -R `whoami` sites/wordpress/wp-content/themes/samarkand-2`
```

should fix it. Or whatever directory you want to start from. This is no dangerous and might come because of you node-installation. It's pretty common and should be fixed in general after running installs with `npm@3.X.X`

Answer (score 2):

While @cwelske gives a "hacky" workaround in his answer, the link he provides to the [bug report](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1502) provides a nicer fix for Gulp 3: use [vinyl-fs](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs).

`npm install vinyl-fs --save-dev`

Modify your gulpfile to use VFS:

Add to your requires block: `var vfs = require('vinyl-fs');`

Modify your output pipe: `.pipe(vfs.dest('./output'));`

The reason I was facing this error is because the files were owned by a more generic group and user so that multiple team members could work on the project together. Obviously Ubuntu doesn't allow you to `chmod` someone else's files. I suspect the OP is in a similar situation (the web-server might own the files).

If you do not require this kind of setup, your other option is to change the files to be owned by your user, something like:

`sudo chown -R me:me .`

Setting file permissions to 777 are not going to help you, because unless you own the file, you cannot `chmod` it without sudo. (Hence it works when you run gulp as sudo.)

Comment: vinyl-fs is not working here with nodejs v10.19.0 , gulp -v CLI version: 2.3.0 Local version: 4.0.2

Answer (score 1):

gulp 3.x [has a bug](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1502) that makes it want to `chown` all files regardless if it already has all required permissions or not. It is supposedly fixed in gulp 4.

The [linked bug](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1502) contains a nice workaround if you know that the files have the correct permissions: Simply replace `fs.chmod` with an empty function in your `gulpfile.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
if (1) fs.chmod = function (a, b, cb) {
    cb(0);
}
```

Comment: this is not working here with nodejs v10.19.0 ,  gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2